# Chatbot nltk.chat.util When the bot cannot answer, that is, when it says None, I want it to say something other than None

Tags: nltk, chat, chatbot

Actually, to put it briefly, I want to interfere with the answer of "chat.converse()" but I can't?

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections

ciftler = [
    ['(Benim adım|adım|ben)(.*)', ["Merhaba %1, nasılsın?"]],
    ['(.*)(Benim adım|adım|ben)', ["Merhaba %1, nasılsın?"]],
    ['(adın ne|adın|isim|ismin ne|ismin var mı|ismin varmı|sana ne diyorlar|sana nasıl seslenelim|bir adın varmı|bir adın var mı)',['onur']],
    ['(merhaba|selam|selamünaleyküm|hey|naber|bro|hi|whatsup)',['merhaba nasılsın,','selam nasılsın ', 'merhaba nasıl gidiyor']],
    ['(iyidir|sağol|sağolasın|eyvallah|iyi iyi|iyi|eh işte|ii|sen)',['süper']],
    ['(iyi değilim|kötü|sik gibi|keyfim yok|hiç iyi sayılmaz|kötüyüm|bilmem|boşver)',['ne oldu ki']],
    ['(Yaşın kaç?|yaş|yaş?|yaşın|Yaşın?|kaç yaşındasın)',['yeni doğdum sayılır']],
    ['(memleket|nerelisin|hangi şehir|hangi ülke|nerdesin|şu an nerdesin|neredesin|şu an neredesin|memleketin)',['şişli, istanbul']],
    ['(.*) gittim',['%1! ok']]
    
]
yansimalar={
    'merhaba': 'merhaba, nasılsın',
    'gittim':'gittin',
    'Selamünaleyküm':'Aleykümselam',
    '12':'21'
}

chat = Chat(ciftler, yansimalar)


def deneme():
    chat.converse()
    while True:
        respond=""
        print('oldu')

deneme()
```

[image]

Even if it says None when I press enter, it does not go to the value I gave.?

Answer (score 0):

i think i've found the answer, based on [this nltk documentation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html). all you need to do is **to not use** the `chat.converse()` **instead use** `chat.respond("user input")` and **add your own loop**, that way you can use
`if chat.respond("user input") is None: print("dont understand")` that way **it will print "dont understand"** everytime the bot doesnt have the answer.